# Get all fields from activerecord, filtered by a column in a different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a simple question but as I am new with sql and Rails I am not able to find the answer.
Lets say I have a Competition model with each competition having many questions.
ie Competition has_many Questions. Question belongs to Competition

Competition has a column "status" with possible values "open" and "closed"

I want to display all questions to the user (irrespective of which competition they belong to) whose competition is still "open"

I am looking for  something like this but this is not syntactically correct.
Question.where(competition.status="open")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is query you want:

```
Question.joins(:competition).where('competitions.status = ?', 'open')
```

But it would be good for you to make this a method inside your `QuestionModel` like

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.from_opened_competitions
    joins(:competition).where('competitions.status = ?', 'open')
  end

end
```